# Cohomology class of a non torsion point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology

Let $k$ be a finitely generated fields of positive characteristic $p>0$.
Let $E$ be an ordinary elliptic curve over $k$ with a non torsion, non zero, rational point $x$.

By the kummer sequence we get a map:
$$\phi:E(k)\rightarrow \varprojlim_n \frac{E(k)}{[p^n]E(k)}\rightarrow \varprojlim_n H^1_{flat}(k,E[p^n])\rightarrow H^1(\Gamma_k,T_p(E))$$

where $T_p(E)$ is $\varprojlim_n E(k^{sep})[p^n]$.

Is it possible to say that $\phi(x)$ is non zero and non torsion? If not, is it possible find some condition on $E$ or $k$ to ensure this?

If think it is always true that the image of $x$ is non torsion in $\varprojlim_n H^1_{flat}(k,E[p^n])$.

Comment: You might find Ulmer's "p-descent in characteristic p" interesting: http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077296358 . By the way, I think you want to assume that $x$ is not divisible by $p$ in $E(k)$.

Comment: Isn't there a long exact sequence in flat cohomology $E[p^n](k) \to E(k) \to E^k \to H^1_{flat}(k,E[p^n]) \to H^1_{flat}(k,E) \dots $? If so then if the image of $x$ is $p^k$ torsion for some $k$, then the image of $p^k x$ in $H^1_{flat}(k, E[p^n])$ is zero for $n$ sufficiently large, which implies that $p^k x$ is $p^n$-divisible for all $n$ sufficiently large, which by Mordell-Weil implies $x$ is torsion.

Comment: @Will Sawin, I agree, but I'd like to understand if the image in $H^1(\Gamma_k,T_p(E)) $ is not torsion. Your proof shows only that it is non torsion in $\varprojlim_n H^1_{flat}(k,E[p^n])$.

Comment: @CrhisWuthrich: could you give some more precise references inside that paper?